# Is there a way to add ManyToMany filed inside current form (not in popup page) in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models in django. the first one is Tag and second one is Article that is related to Tag models via ManyToMany fields.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

In Django **admin panel**, When I want to and one or more tag(s) for an article, a **popup** appears to add tag.
I want to add tags inside the current form. Is it possible?

Comment: No. But you can (1) either write custom JS to handle creation of Tags via AJAX, which I don't think is worth the effort; (2) or you can create a new `CharField` in your model to accept tags in plain string separated by comma. Then in your model's save method you can check if provided tags exist in db or not. If they don't exist, then create them and finally add the tags to the actual `tags` m2m field.

Comment: I think the second way is faster for develop. thanks anyway

Comment: Also, don't forget about the removing tags functionality. If a tag exists in `tags` m2m field, but later is removed from the `CharField`, then you may want to remove it from the m2m as well.